# iOS - Cell image blurred

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have placed an image in a UITableViewCell and for some reason, the image is a bit blurred...

This is what I'm using:

```
NSURL *urlForProfileImage = [NSURL URLWithString: [_currentTweet[@"user"] objectForKey:@"profile_image_url_https"]];
UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlForProfileImage]];

cell.imageView.image = thumbnail;
```

Is there another way to provide the desired result but maintain the images quality?

Comment: Why you are not setting image directly like cell.imageView.image = thumbnail

Comment: @Anil even if i just use that, its blurred..

Comment: @user3150273: It may vary size of image and your imageview. In that case, you can resize image according to imageview.

Comment: Please don’t use `dataWithContentsOfURL` because it is synchronous. It will block your UI (and may force-quit you app). Please consider AFNetworking.

Comment: @user3150273 That will be image problem, may be a low resolution image you are downloading.

Comment: @Anil I'm getting it directly for twitter.

Comment: can you please post the image link here?
it seems that the image size if smaller than the area where you are displaying it. and also mention the imageViews height and width.

Comment: @shahil https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/192098593/Apple_normal.png

Comment: this image is 48x48... please tell me the height and width of your imageView

Comment: @shahil i used the `cell.imageView.image = thumbnail` how do i find out the height and width of the `imageView`?

Comment: Use this code `NSLog(@"cell.imageView.frame.size.width : %f  cell.imageView.frame.size.height : %f",cell.imageView.frame.size.width,cell.imageView.frame.size.height);` and let us know the log response

Answer (score 1):

**Reason :**

The default imageView size is 40x40 and so your image needs to be 80x80 pixels (retina display).

But the image that you are getting from the "pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/192098593/Apple_normal.png" is 48x48.

And so it is blurred.

**Solution :**

One option is that you add a custom imageView which is 24x24. (width : 24 & height : 24) Then your image will not show blurred.

Or, you can try modifying the height and width of the imageView by subclassing the class UITableViewCell and using its layoutSubviews method. The "trick" is to write layout code in this method, otherwise the code does not have any effect :

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,24,24);
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,24,24);
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    CGRect tmpFrame = self.textLabel.frame;
    tmpFrame.origin.x = 30;
    self.textLabel.frame = tmpFrame;

    tmpFrame = self.detailTextLabel.frame;
    tmpFrame.origin.x = 30;
    self.detailTextLabel.frame = tmpFrame;

}
```

Comment: Most likely this is the correct answer, assuming a tableview cell is around 50px in height and your image is around 50x50px, a retina screen requires an image of 100x100px. So you'll need to fetch the larger avatar image from Twitter for retina devices.